# How to send a base64 encoded image via tcp from python to node js?

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, ip

I am basically working on a project and got stuck at this point. I tried normal tcp but later found that the image was partially transported of max length around 65,000 at node js end. But the total encoded image length is around 3 times of 65000 at python side. The image is basically a screen-shot of my desktop of resolution around 1920 x 1020.
Here is my python side code

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 9898        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    print("-- start --")
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("-- accepted --")
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print("R : ", data)
            if not data:
                break
            print("sending data")
            # b64str is a pre computed string of length around 65000*3
            conn.sendall(bytes(b64str, 'utf-8'))
```

Here is Node js side code

```
client.connect(9898, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('CONNECTED : img-data-channel');
});
// buff is a buffer queue that stores the base64 encoded string
client.on('data', function(data) {
    str_data = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, data);
    buff.push_data(str_data);
    // console.log("Received: img-data type : ", typeof(str_data), "  size : ", str_data.length) ;
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('DISCONNECTED : img-data-channel');
});
```

Thankyou in advance.